# Переход на следующую или предыдущую неделю

Tags: java, android

Есть активити с двумя кнопками "<<" и ">>". Также есть `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();`. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку ">>" в переменные `m1` и `m2` записывались `timestamp` понедельника и воскресенья следующей недели, а когда нажали на кнопку "<<" записались `timestamp` понедельника и воскресенья предыдущей недели?

Comment: не очень понятно что именно вы хотите сделать, и при чем здесь timestamp, когда у календаря есть возможности брать дни недели

Comment: Проще говоря при нажатии на одну кнопку нужно получать следующую неделю, а именно понедельник и воскресенье следующей недели, а при нажатии на другую кнопку понедельник и воскресенье предыдущей недели. Например сейчас неделя с 6по 12 января. Если нажать одну кнопку нужно получить понедельник и воскресенье следующей недели и наоборот

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то ваш код, и код, который по вашей ссылке не совсем то что нужно выдавал. Текущую неделю например выдавал как с 12 по 18 января. Нашел другое решение.

**Текущая неделя**

```
private void setWeekCurrent() {
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    while(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY)
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);
    }

    txtPeriod.setText(calendar.getTime() + " ");

    mills1 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);

    txtPeriod.append(" / " + calendar.getTime() + " ");

    mills2 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
}
```

**Следующая неделя**

```
private void setWeekNext() {
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    while(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY)
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);
    }

    txtPeriod.setText(calendar.getTime() + " ");

    mills1 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);

    txtPeriod.append(" / " + calendar.getTime() + " ");

    mills2 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
}
```

**Предыдущая неделя**

```
private void setWeekPrev() {
    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

    calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);

    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    while(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY)
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,-1);
    }

    txtPeriod.setText(calendar.getTime() + " ");

    mills1 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);

    txtPeriod.append(" / " + calendar.getTime() + " ");

    mills2 = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так для текущей недели:

```
SimpleDateFormat displayDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyyy"));

final Calendar calenderThisWeek = Calendar.getInstance();
calenderThisWeek.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
String strWek = displayDate.format(calenderThisWeek.getTime()); // dd-mmm-yyyy
calenderThisWeek.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);  
String endWek = displayDate.format(calenderThisWeek.getTime()); // dd-mmm-yyyy
```

так для предыдущей:

```
final Calendar calenderpreviousWeek = Calendar.getInstance();
calenderpreviousWeek.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -1);
calenderpreviousWeek.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
String strWek = displayDate.format(calenderThisWeek.getTime()); // dd-mmm-yyyy
calenderpreviousWeek.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);          
String endWek = displayDate.format(calenderpreviousWeek.getTime()); // dd-mmm-yyyy
```

и для следующей:

```
final Calendar calenderNextWeek = Calendar.getInstance();
calenderNextWeek.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, +1);
calenderNextWeek.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
String strWek = displayDate.format(calenderNextWeek.getTime()); // dd-mmm-yyyy
calenderNextWeek.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);  
String endWek = displayDate.format(calenderNextWeek.getTime()); // dd-mmm-yyyy
```

Вот [статья](https://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html) где более-менее нормально расписано как решать данную проблему и [вопрос_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927565/android-week-view-how-can-we-get-all-days-of-a-next-and-previous-week)  / [вопрос_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856475/how-to-get-next-week-of-dates-from-calender) на enSO

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать как комп окажется под рукой.